# Data Factory - Invalid reference to the managed Virtual Network 'default'

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to create a managed integration runtime through the ADF Portal. When I select "Create" on the "Virtual network" tab, I get the following error:

> Failed to save integration runtime. Invalid reference to the managed
> Virtual Network 'default'. The managed Virtual Network does not exist.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I do have the same issue. @rob-bowman Please post the solution if you have found one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found that something had happened while creating a managed virtual network in my data factory, and in my git repo under path/src/managedVirtualNetwork there is a file with the reference to the managed Virtual Network named 'default'.

If you delete that reference(in your collaboration branch) and republish the data factory, you should be able to create your integration runtime.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot upvote, but Hagbart's solution works!

Additional repro steps:

- using DevOps repo from existing DataFactory
- branch that collaboration branch (main->new_branch)
- creating new Data Factory
- from DF Studio, setting the new DevOps repo and using new_branch as collaboration branch
- try to create a Managed Integration Runtime in Azure for Virtual Network

Error is exactly as stated in original post, and deleting the ManagedVirtualNetwork folder in repo solved the error instantly.

Thanks for that answer (and please upvote the original answer not mine).